# Creating a totally new project in TFS using s Branch of another Project

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, reparenting

My company wishes to create a whole separate product (software system) from code which has been branched from an existing product. Our source control is TFVC on Azure DevOps. I need to know how to create the new Project using the branched code.

I am wondering if we were to reparent the branch to 'No Parent', could we create the new project using that code?

Comment: There is no such thing as "TFS" source control. Is it TFVC, or is it Git?

Comment: Sorry, it is TFVC

Comment: Create a new project and copy files from the old project in the local to the new folder, then push to the TFS not work for you?